# How to fix The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in microsoft exchange wed service

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to read and send email using Microsoft exchange webservice API. I tried to run this code for Outlook version 2010 and 2016 in my VMs its showing

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

where as same code for office 365 its working fine. I even tried manual accessing outlook mails with URL and credentials and I am able to do it but through code.

Comment: Well, you should probably then include a (minimal) code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =    ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password );
service.Url = new Uri(Service_URL);
PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itempropertyset.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi, we are receiving attached error also, it seems to be relates with your issue. We have started receiving this today by the morning. Could it be like a Windows update or something? We are still investigating this issue.

I’ll try upgrading the .net environment and replacing the web.config currently 4.5.2 with the 4.6.1

**EDIT:**

Yes, we have solved that issue. We used IIS Crypto 2.0 software to revert all tls settings to it's server defaults on Day-1. Then don't forget to restart the server of course. I think that Windows updates messed up with the TLS settings on Windows servers. Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I dont have access to IIS. I am using this coding inside 1 windows based application.